# How to set width of rows as same as the header row width in dynamic table layout

Tags: android, width, tablelayout, android-layout-weight

I have a dynamic table layout like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:padding="10sp"
    android:textColor="@color/accent_material_light"
    android:id="@+id/tabTitle"/>

            <TableLayout
                android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:stretchColumns="*"
                android:shrinkColumns="*"
                android:layout_below="@+id/tabTitle"
                >
            </TableLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
```

now i want to set width of rows as same as the header row width in dynamic table layout. And i want to set the column values should be equally distribute according to the different screen sizes.

eg. I have 4 columns say Id, name, subject name and subject mark. These values should get equal space even if they are in different screen size devices.

But the values coming under these columns should have their respective header width.

```
  private void buildTable() {


        TableRow tr_head = new TableRow(getActivity());
     //   tr_head.setId(10);
        tr_head.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
        tr_head.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        tr_head.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        tr_head.setWeightSum(4f);

        TextView label_id = new TextView(getActivity());
   //     label_date.setId(20);
        label_id.setText("ID");
        label_id.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        label_id.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        tr_head.addView(label_id);// add the column to the table row here

        TextView label_name = new TextView(getActivity());
        label_name .setText("Student Name"); // set the text for the header
        label_name .setTextColor(Color.WHITE); // set the color
        label_name .setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5); // set the padding (if required)
        tr_head.addView(label_name ); // add the column to the table row here

        TextView label_sub = new TextView(getActivity());
        label_sub .setText("Subject Name"); // set the text for the header
        label_sub .setTextColor(Color.WHITE); // set the color
        label_sub .setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5); // set the padding (if required)
        tr_head.addView(label_sub ); // add the column to the table row here

        TextView label_mark = new TextView(getActivity());
        label_mark.setText("Subject Mark"); // set the text for the header
        label_mark.setTextColor(Color.WHITE); // set the color
        label_mark.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5); // set the padding (if required)
        tr_head.addView(label_mark); // add the column to the table row here

        tl.addView(tr_head, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                0,
                TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));

       .....

                        // Create the table row
                        TableRow tr = new TableRow(getActivity());
                        tr.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(
                                R.drawable.row_color));
                        tr.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(
                                0,
                                TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));

                        //Create two columns to add as table data

                        TextView labelid = new TextView(getActivity());
                        labelid .setText(id);
                        labelid .setPadding(2, 0, 5, 0);
                        labelid .setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                        tr.addView(labelid );

                        TextView labelname = new TextView(getActivity());
                        labelname .setText(name);
                        labelname .setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                        tr.addView(labelname );

                        TextView labelSub = new TextView(getActivity());
                        labelSub .setText(sub);
                        labelSub .setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                        tr.addView(labelSub );

                        TextView labelSubMark = new TextView(getActivity());
                        labelSubMark .setText("mark");
                        labelSubMark .setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                        tr.addView(labelSubMark);

                        // finally add this to the table row
                        tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                                0,
                                TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));

                    } while (c.moveToNext());
                }
            }
        }


    }
```

please help anyone...tried everything but all in vain.

Comment: I don't think the standard android layouts have this ability.  You might do well to implement your own custom view (derived from TableLayout or GridView?) that implements this custom layout logic.

Comment: What is " t l " in the above code? Can you please share the proper and complete code, so that I can check properly.

Comment: public class TableViewFragment extends Fragment {
        TableLayout tl;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.tableviewlist, null);

        tl = (TableLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.tableLayout1); 
        buildTable();
        return view;
    }

Comment: @AndroidBeginner Sorry, it's too much to put here, but if you search for things like android custom views and layouts there will be a lot of material to learn.